# Can't load edits to my website

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to get my gigs page to load content at the push of a button but it doesn't seem to be loading the content this is what i have

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#apr").click(function(){
                $("#gigs").load(gigs/april13.html);
            }); 
        });
    </script>
    <title>Where We're Playing</title>
</head>
```

Where,
 `#apr` is the button id,
 `#gigs` is the id of the div where I want it to appear and
on the side I have an unordered list containing the button(s).
the file `gigs/april13.html` is the url of the gigs info.

This is [the gigs page](http://boozebrostempsite.comeze.com/gigs.php) I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the `jQuery` API and also you have a typo mistake.

Try this instead:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#apr").click(function(){
                $("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html');
            }); 
        });
    </script>
    <title>Where We're Playing</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help folks, gonna update now, see if it works

Comment: This is broken, you need a closing `</script>`  becuase `<script>` tags are not self closing

Comment: Thanks for the note. a closing </script> tag has been added.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the `jQuery` library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also need to do what @tymeJV said and make sure you keep the load URL in quotes

You may want to change click to `.on`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#apr").on("click",function(){
        $("#gigs").load("gigs/april13.html");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Does that go in the header? Edit: Nevermind, I copped on sorry

Comment: Yes, after your stylesheet `<link>` and before your `<script>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot quotes around your path

```
$("#gigs").load("gigs/april13.html");
```

Comment: I updated the site to include the quotes just there and it didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

After view your page source, the obvious reason is that you haven't included jQuery library.

Put this under your referenced css file and before your jQuery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: using jquery latest is not a good idea, as functions get removed and will end up causing your website to break until you notice or someone else alerts you to it.. always stick to a version rather than latest